# GHUnit install, it provides a xcodeproj/ext LoadError

Tags: unit-testing, ios8, xcode6, gh-unit

When running the `ghunit install -n ProjectName` I get the following error.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/ext (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ghunit-1.0.3/lib/ghunit/project.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ghunit-1.0.3/lib/ghunit.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ghunit-1.0.3/bin/ghunit:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/ghunit:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/ghunit:23:in `<main>'
```

I have also tried to manually add a target, add the GHUnit.framework and run. It was working fine for a sample simple unit test until I needed to test my classes. So I added the headers, wrote some code and then it gave me undefined symbols.
Tried adding the cocoapod lib, Apple additional frameworks, almost what I use in my main project app target, nothing could overcome the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has been fixed in the master by a collaborator after I reported it on Github.